# Strange behaviour with MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

The following code runs fine except that after the second MySQL query the script seems to have stopped outputting HTML although I get no errors. The counter however runs fine and I have pinpointed the problem (it's with the while loop). I know this because the "Hello?" string isn't outputted. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

```
$db = new MySQLConnect();
$db->query("SELECT * FROM links;");
$db->run();

while ($row = $db->row()->fetch()) {
    $id    = $row["id"];
    $count = $row["count"];
    $count = $count + 1;

    var_dump($id);
    var_dump($_GET["id"]);

    if ($id == $_GET["id"]) {
        try {
            $db->query("UPDATE links SET count=count + 1 WHERE id=$id;");
            $db->run();
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }         
    print_r($id . ": " . $count);
}
echo "Hello?";
```

Comment: Can be because result of second query overwrites previous? Results are stored inside class so next overwrites previous. You need to use two separate `$db` to make it work.

Comment: What is `MySQLConnect`? Whatever it is, you seem to be re-using the same object to run your in-loop query which would surely overwrite the statement used in `$db->row()->fetch()`

Comment: How would I clear the query?

Comment: LOL. Thanks guys. I created a second database object and it works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentionaed above in comments, you're overwriting result set. I didn't test but should works as expected.

```
$db = new MySQLConnect();
$db->query("SELECT * FROM links;");
$db->run();

while ($row = $db->row()->fetch()) {
    $id    = $row["id"];
    $count = $row["count"];
    $count = $count + 1;

    var_dump($id);
    var_dump($_GET["id"]);

    if ($id == $_GET["id"]) {
        try {
            $stmt = new MySQLConnect();
            $stmt->query("UPDATE links SET count=count + 1 WHERE id=$id;");
            $stmt->run();
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }         
    print_r($id . ": " . $count);
}
echo "Hello?";
```